# Find all customer pairs where one has purchased a superset of product compared to the other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables that describe a database that is used by a business to manage online orders:

```
     orders
   o_id c_id
    1    1
    2    1
    3    2
    4    3
    5    3


  order_items
  o_id  p_id
   1     1
   2     2
   3     1
   3     2
   3     8
   4     1
   4     2
   5     8
   5     9

  customers
 c_id   name
  1     Mark
  2     Lisa
  3     Sean
```

I want to find ALL pairs of customers where the second customer in the pair has purchased AT LEAST all of the products that the first customer in the pair has purchased. I can't seem to figure this out! My best attempt was a joining of orders and order_items as a table and cross joining that table with itself to get all of the pairs that have purchased the same product. I can't seem to reduce it from there.

```
 Expected Output
  c_id1  c_id2
    1      2
    1      3
    2      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-join for this purpose.  It helps to have a count of the products for each customer.  So, this defines a CTE that has that information along with the unique customer/product pairs:

```
with ci as (
      select c.c_id, o.p_id, count(*) over (partition by c_id) as cnt
      from order_items oi join
           customers c
           on c.o_id = o.o_id
      group by c.c_id, o.p_id
     )
select ci1.c_id, ci2.c_id
from ci ci1 join
     ci ci2
     on ci1.p_id = oi2.p_id
group by ci1.c_id, ci2.c_id, ci1.cnt
having count(*) = ci1.cnt;
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, as you use "c.o_id" but the customers table doesn't have an o_id. I tried this out on a larger set and it seems like it I'm getting incorrect results. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5878f8b4c21374cf36bd64c5072fd46f)

Comment: @GregorySiot . . . Wrong count in the CTE.

Comment: How could I alter this to do the complete opposite? As in find any pair where the second customer doesn't have any products in common to the first customer.

Comment: @GregorySiot . . . That should be asked as a new question.